# Is there any Python IDE that do not need Admin for installing?

Tags: python

We need admin for installing some software which it will take nearly a month for them to install for us. So I want to find some Python IDE that can install without admin (Windows 7). Any suggest?

Comment: You don't really need an IDE to write Python code... a good text editor is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Pyzo

http://www.pyzo.org/

It's a portable, cross-platform Python distribution which comes with an editor named IEP. You can even put it in a USB stick. It's geared towards scientific uses though.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Considering IDLE can be considered as an IDE you can have a look into the following two options

[Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/browser)

[Movable IDLE](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/movableidle.html)

Netbeans had support for Python till 6.9. You can use a portable version of it

[Portable Netbeans](http://portableapps.com/node/24381)

If you want to use Eclipse for Python development, here is a Portable Version. You need [PyDev](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyDev) to work with Eclipse.

[Portable Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipseportable/)

[Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/) as a Python distro and [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) as IDE.

Comment: I do not have NetBean on this pc.

Comment: @ThanaDaray: You can use a Portable Version of Netbeans from the link provided. No installation is required

Comment: It did not mention that it can be use with Python. (I check the website.)

Comment: @ThanaDaray: Support is available till version 6.9. Netbeans 7.x is yet to support Python.

Comment: Check the [plugin page](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/)

Comment: I cannot use it as it required Java 1.6 or higher.. This pc do not have them.

Comment: @ThanaDaray: You can also get a [portable Java](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable)

Comment: also, jython comes as a standalone jar

Answer (score 3):

let me add the [amazing editor](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) spyderlib !

Answer (score 2):

http://www.portablepython.com/

"Some of the most popular free Python IDE’s come preinstalled and preconfigured with Portable Python." - http://www.portablepython.com/wiki/Documentation

or you could use: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/movableidle.html (IDLE)

Comment: Any other that better than Python Shell?

Comment: As mentioned, there are several IDE's preinstalled in that package. For example: http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/

Comment: pyscripter required admin to install

Comment: Not if you use that one inside of portablepython .. there it is preinstalled and ready to use!

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use something like https://www.pythonanywhere.com.